# Android : Connect to MySql

Tags: android, mysql

Can anyone help with a good tutorial on Android Studio , connecting with MySql. I tried many , that are available in google. But all their php code, whenever uploaded to my website root fall into ERROR 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to connect an app directly to MySQL or any database engine, it should be done with a back end, using web services to `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` data.

Comment: Yes. Can u suggest any similar codes for reference. For example , a login.php & mainActivity.java codes.. But it should work neatly

Comment: One easy way to go is using `Retrofit`, which documentation is [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).. If you have any problems still, let me know, so I can explain you briefly how to use `Retrofit`